# Difficulty positioning text on UIButton

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have an ipad app with Round Rect buttons. I have two problems.

1 - I can't get the text to be centred. I have tried:

```
menuButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = 0;
```

but it does not seem to work. The line break mode is set to wrap.

2 - on another button where the text is "Using e-maths" the hyphen is used as a real hyphen and therefore the text is wrapped with "Using e-" on one line and "Maths" on the second.

Any help with these queries much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` does not resize its title label if you change the text during runtime. You have to call `[button sizeToFit];` or somehow otherwise change the button's frame for it to resize title label. You can also subclass `UIButton` extending `setTitle:forControlState:` method to update label's size every time title text is changed.

Comment: Again, I am sorry but I am confused here. I do not think I want to change the size of the text, just Centre it. Also I am having trouble even changing the text during runtime as it says that these properties are all read-only. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can sub class the UIButton class and you can add this method in the draw rect of the new sub classed button

```
[button titleLabel]drawTextInRect:frame];
```

where the frame is relative to the bounds of the button, here you can position the text of the label correctly as you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't understand what I am to do here. If the button is called menuButton how do I use what you are saying to centre the text? Sorry but how do you sub class the UIButton?

Comment: @richard-griffiths say you have a button of size 60x30px and you can reposition the text as [[button titleLabel]drawTextInRect:CGRectMake(10,5,self.view.bounds.size.width-20,self.view.bounds.size.height-10)];    So what you are doing here is you are starting the label 10px from the left margin and right margin and 5px from top margin and bottom margin.